# Different wallpaper for portrait and landscape

Tags: cyanogenmod, wallpaper, nova-launcher

I used an iPad some years ago and it had an option to choose different images in portrait and landscape mode. I am on a Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 10.1 with Cyanognmod and I also use a OnePlus 2. I am using Nova lauchner.

My question is:

Is it possible to set different images for portrait and landscape orientation? (It is okay to use different apps than Nova Launcher)

I hope this is the right StackExchange sub"forum" for this question.

Thanks for answering,

Florian Reisinger

Comment: Installed CM version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) app here.

## [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate)

Setup a flow like this:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Location of relevant blocks:

- Interface → Screen Orientation?
- Settings  → Wallpaper image set

After setting it up, make sure to install the permission it asks for - set wallpaper.

This worked in my COS12 and PA build of Android 5.1 but somehow failed in Android 5.1 nightly build of Vanir ROM.

---

## [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)

Try the [trial version](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html), before buying from Play Store.

- Profile: State → Display → Display Orientation →Portrait
- Task: (Actions): Display → Set Wallpaper → fill the details
- For landscape orientation, you can either add an [exit task](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide_summary.html#activity_main.html) by long pressing the task entry next to linked profile under Profiles tab and choosing "Add exit task", or setup a new profile for landscape orientation and create a new task for it.

  For latter approach, make sure to disable Restore Settings  for both the profiles. A profile's properties can be accessed by long-pressing the profile and tapping the settings icon.

Tasker worked in both Android 5.0 and 5.1 ROMs installed in my device.

Comment: Automate did help.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily. 
Open an image you want to set as wallpaper in gallery 
In menu->set picture as ->Nova wallpaper 
In the crop screen choose crop icon
(2nd icon left of bottom) choose whatever rotation you want. 
It will work.

Comment: I am unable to see that icon.... Would it be possible to add an screenshot?

Comment: Visit link for screenshot 
[IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/2ch1evo.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: I am unable to find this screen (only thing I have with latest Nova Prome on OnePlus 2: http://i68.tinypic.com/2q03539.png ) - I only have this screen